# Problem with small program: Error: "Charting Private pvar"

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, warning-messages, debugging, application

Im in the making of a smaller self-running application. I have made a small piece of the program as it has to look in the end. However, sometimes when i change some of the input for either "demand" or "supply" it doesnt change the output, but comes up with a lot of errors. On the other side - it works exactly as wished sometimes. I think it might be a problem with the graph. Please help me fixing my program (try to change the input a few times)! The code is here:

```
DynamicModule[{Demand, Supply, G, F, X1, Y1, Y2, Graf, Slutinterval,CS, PS, SS}, Manipulate[
G = Q /. Solve[Supply == Demand, Q][[1]];
F = Block[{Q = G}, Supply];
CS = N[Integrate[Demand, {Q, 0, G}] - (F*G)];
PS = N[(F*G) - Integrate[Supply, {Q, 0, G}]];
SS = CS + PS;
X1 := G/6;
Y1 := ((Block[{Q = 0}, Demand]) - F)/2 + F;
Y2 := F - ((F - (Block[{Q = 0}, Supply]))/2);
Slutinterval := G + G/100*30;
Column[{
StringForm["Først bestemmes ligvægtsmængden og prisen. Dette gøres ved at finde Supply = Demand:"],
StringForm["Supply = Demand \[DoubleLongRightArrow] Solve[`1` == `2`,Q] = `3`", Supply, Demand, G],
StringForm["Q = ``", G],
StringForm["På samme vis bestemmes den tihørende optimale pris:"],
StringForm["P = Supply(``) = ``", G, F],
StringForm["Nu kan henholdsvis Consumer Surplus, Producer Surplus, og Social Welfare bestemmes:"],
StringForm["CS = Integrate[Demand,{Q,0,Q}] - (P * Q) = Integrate[`1`,{Q,0,`2`}] - (`3` * `2`) = `4`", Demand, G, F, CS],
StringForm["PS = (P * Q) - Integrate[Supply,{Q,0,Q}] = (`1` * `2`) - Integrate[`3`,{Q,0,`2`}] = `4`", F, G, Supply, PS],
StringForm["SS = CS + PS = `1` + `2` = `3`", CS, PS, SS],
Show[(Plot[{Supply, Demand}, {Q, 0, Slutinterval},
   AxesLabel -> {"Q", "P"},
   ImageSize -> 700,
   PlotLabels -> {"Supply", "Demand", " "}]), (Plot[{Supply, Demand, F}, {Q, 0, G}, Filling -> 2 -> F, 
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, Blue, {Thick, Dashed, Black}},
   PlotLabels -> Placed[{"CS"}, {X1, Y1}]]), (Plot[{Supply, Demand}, {Q, 0, G}, Filling -> 1 -> F,
   PlotLabels -> Placed[{"PS"}, {X1, Y2}]]), (ContourPlot[{Q == G}, {Q, 0, Slutinterval}, {y, 0, F}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Black, Dashed, Thick}]), (ListPlot[{Labeled[{0, F}, "P"], Labeled[{G, 0}, "Q"], {G, F}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]])]}],
Style["Velfærdsteori ved markedsligevægt (FK)", 20, Bold],
Style["Denne funktion beregner ligevægtspris og mængde på et marked. Ydermere beregner og skitserer", 12, Plain],
Style["funktionen Consumer Surplus, Producer Surplus samt Social Surplus.", 12, Plain],
Control@{{Demand, -Q + 98}, InputField, ImageSize -> Full},
Control@{{Supply, 0.5 Q + 2}, InputField, ImageSize -> Full}
]]
```

Comment: Awkward design takes 50% of the CPU and it is not clear what is continuously calculated there. Need to add options.

Comment: @AlexTrounev - Just ignore the calculations i think its setup of manipulate or column which is wrong maybe?

Comment: You're making a lot of assignments inside `Manipulate`.  When symbols that appear inside `Manipulate` change value, it usually triggers an update.  That can lead to infinite loops.  Look up `TrackedSymbols`, `Initialization`, or refactor your code. `With` can be useful for injecting a temporary calculation without creating a permanent symbol and without triggering an update.

Comment: @MichaelE2 OMG your the best man! "TrackedSymbols" worked perfectly!